# C structure or a function?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, kvm

I am trying to understand kvm code in linux and came across tjis:

```
    static int (*const svm_exit_handlers[])(struct vcpu_svm *svm) = {
[SVM_EXIT_READ_CR0]         = cr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_CR3]         = cr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_CR4]         = cr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_CR8]         = cr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_CR0_SEL_WRITE]        = emulate_on_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_CR0]            = cr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_CR3]            = cr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_CR4]            = cr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_CR8]            = cr8_write_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR0]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR1]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR2]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR3]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR4]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR5]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR6]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_READ_DR7]         = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR0]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR1]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR2]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR3]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR4]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR5]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR6]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WRITE_DR7]            = dr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_EXCP_BASE + DB_VECTOR]    = db_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_EXCP_BASE + BP_VECTOR]    = bp_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_EXCP_BASE + UD_VECTOR]    = ud_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_EXCP_BASE + PF_VECTOR]    = pf_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_EXCP_BASE + NM_VECTOR]    = nm_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_EXCP_BASE + MC_VECTOR]    = mc_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_INTR]             = intr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_NMI]              = nmi_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_SMI]              = nop_on_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_INIT]             = nop_on_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_VINTR]            = interrupt_window_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_RDPMC]            = rdpmc_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_CPUID]            = cpuid_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_IRET]                         = iret_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_INVD]                         = emulate_on_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_PAUSE]            = pause_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_HLT]              = halt_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_INVLPG]           = invlpg_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_INVLPGA]          = invlpga_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_IOIO]             = io_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_MSR]              = msr_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_TASK_SWITCH]          = task_switch_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_SHUTDOWN]         = shutdown_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_VMRUN]            = vmrun_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_VMMCALL]          = vmmcall_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_VMLOAD]           = vmload_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_VMSAVE]           = vmsave_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_STGI]             = stgi_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_CLGI]             = clgi_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_SKINIT]           = skinit_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_WBINVD]                       = emulate_on_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_MONITOR]          = invalid_op_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_MWAIT]            = invalid_op_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_XSETBV]           = xsetbv_interception,
[SVM_EXIT_NPF]              = pf_interception,
```

};

I am well versed in C but haven't come across this anywhere and really confused if this is a function or a structure declaration or otherwise. Any help would be gladly accepted.

Comment: The existence of the `const` keyword makes this a C++ problems, not a C construct

Comment: But, this is a part of the linux kernel code and is present in linux/arch/x86/kvm/ as the file vmx.c

Comment: @SGM1: Certainly not!  `const` is valid C, and designated initializers are not valid C++.  Besides that, no C++ is allowed in the linux kernel tree.

Comment: @SGM1, `const` is in C since 1999.

Comment: @BenVoigt and JensGustedt. Ok, I was told it wasn't present in C, but now I know, thanks

Comment: `const` was in C89, the first ever C standard.

Answer (score 6):

This is an array of function pointers.

It is initialized using designated initializers.

EDIT:  The declaration can be read as follows --

declare `svm_exit_handlers` as a static array of const pointer to function that takes pointer to `struct vcpu_svm` and returns `int`

(You may find http://www.cdecl.org somewhat helpful for parsing difficult C declarations.)

In more colloquial English, that means this is an array of function pointers.  The functions pointed to are of the form `int foo(struct vcpu_svm *svm)`.

EDIT:  The designated initializers may be somewhat confusing too.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: Thank You. I could understand vm_exit_handlers[] part but was confused by the presence of "(*const svm_exit_handlers[])(struct vcpu_svm *svm)". Also, could you please elaborate further by breaking down the declaration?

Comment: Breakdown: `typedef int FUNC_TYPE(struct vcpu_svm *);  static FUNCTYPE *const svm_exit_handlers[] = { ... }; `   The `const` means that the values in the array cannot be changed (as opposed to the functions being pointed to, which wouldn't make sense). The `static` means that `svm_exit_handlers` is only visible within the current unit (not that the functions being pointed to are static).

Comment: I don't understand the presence of the square brackets in the curly brackets, thanks for the link, will use those in my next project XD, thank i was look for that here at SO

Comment: @SGM1 -- The square brackets inside the curly-braces {} are designated initializers of the array.  It means, e.g., `svm_exit_handlers[SVM_EXIT_READ_CR0] = cr_interception`.

Comment: Ya i just appended to my previous comment before the 5 min mark had been reached, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a initialization of an array of function pointers that takes a (struct vcpu_svm *svm) and returns an int.

Comment: What do you mean by "takes (struct vcpu_svm *svm) ". I am confused by the presence of struct there. Thanks.